# c# - Filling a Repeater without Refreshing the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Sup!

I do have a menu with many options like this:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server" OnClick="lb1_Click">Click me!</asp:LinkButton></li>
```

And I do fill a repeater with different sources depending which linkbutton the user press.

```
protected void lb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater1.DataSource = /*getting the data*/
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Everytime I press a link button it works perfectly! But It does Refresh the page, and I don't want it to happen.

Wanna a dynamic refill.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Wrap your `Repeater` and `LinkButton` in `UpdatePanel`

Comment: Menu items are on separate page(master page) Or same page that contain repeaters?

Comment: Maybe ajax back to the server rather than doing a full page post back?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Gonna try it, thanks.

Comment: @JitendraRangpariya Same Page (im not using masterpages on this project)

Comment: @JKerny Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I will like you to consider using a UpdatePanel  like below.now its a ajax call and will not refresh. Consider reading update modes of Update Panel also

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="yourPanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server" OnClick="lb1_Click">Click me!</asp:LinkButton></li>
        <!-- Your Repeater HERE -->
            </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content into update panel so it will prevent the page refresh. please see below are the full example so you can get more ideas,

**.ASPX**

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lb1" runat="server" OnClick="lb1_Click">Click me!</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lb2" runat="server" OnClick="lb2_Click">Click me!</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lb3" runat="server" OnClick="lb3_Click">Click me!</asp:LinkButton>
            <br />
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("Website") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**.CS**

```
protected void lb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<testtt> list = new List<testtt>();
    list.Add(new testtt() { Website = "www.gmail.com" });
    Repeater1.DataSource = list;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
protected void lb2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<testtt> list = new List<testtt>();
    list.Add(new testtt() { Website = "www.facebook.com" });
    Repeater1.DataSource = list;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
protected void lb3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<testtt> list = new List<testtt>();
    list.Add(new testtt() { Website = "www.google.com" });
    Repeater1.DataSource = list;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```